# facebook links.getStats and comma with urls

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink

Function links.getStats separate urls with comma. What if I have comma with my urls? In the documentation I found nothing :(.

http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=,http://meczyki.pl/obrazki,32,http://meczyki.pl/obrazki,33,http://meczyki.pl/obrazki,34,http://meczyki.pl/obrazki,35,http://meczyki.pl/obrazki,36,http://meczyki.pl/obrazki,37,http://meczyki.pl/obrazki,38,http://meczyki.pl/obrazki,39,http://meczyki.pl/obrazki,40,http://meczyki.pl/obrazki,41,http://meczyki.pl/obrazki,42 etc...

Please help

Answer (score 3):

Double-URL-encode the comma, as `%252C`:

http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=http://meczyki.pl/obrazki%252C32,http://meczyki.pl/obrazki%252C33,http://meczyki.pl/obrazki%252C34,http://meczyki.pl/obrazki%252C35,http://meczyki.pl/obrazki%252C36,http://meczyki.pl/obrazki%252C37,http://meczyki.pl/obrazki%252C38,http://meczyki.pl/obrazki%252C39,http://meczyki.pl/obrazki%252C40,http://meczyki.pl/obrazki%252C41,http://meczyki.pl/obrazki%252C42